Ubuntu installed version 24.04 differs from "About this sytem" value 12
My installed Ubuntu version is 24.04
l
sb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

On the other hand, "About this system" reports "Ubuntu 12"
How can I sync my version?
